# In Linux compare File byte per byte in 2 folder and look for duplicate

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have several image files (.jpg, png and more) containing photos in 2 directories, how can I compare the files in the 2 directories byte by byte using Bash under Linux so as to:

1) highlight duplicate files in both directories on a stdout or file

2) delete only 1 of the duplicate files, e.g. the most recent one.

Comment: You can use the `cmp` command to compare binary files to determine if they are the same. Using that command, make an attempt at a script and then pose a more specific question.

Comment: If the files are identical, why do you care about the timestamp when determining which one to delete?

Comment: @WilliamPursell in fact, it is not important which one is deleted, the one in the second search directory can be deleted

Comment: Rather than compare every file against all others, consider generating an md5 checksum once for each file, then sorting and finding duplicate checksums... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34748516/2836621

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need byte-per-byte comparison. Calculating checksum and working with it is easier and probability of collision is very low. It can also save some time if you want to perform this multiple times with slow disk.

---

I have two directories (`a` and `b`) with these files:

```
$ ls *
a:
agetty  agetty-2  badblocks  bridge  btrfs  btrfs-image  lvreduce  lvreduce-2  resize2fs

b:
agetty  agetty-2  bridge
```

#### 1 Calculate checksums first

I will calculate checksums for all *files* and sort them:

```sh
find a b -type f | xargs sha256sum | sort > cksums
```

You can also use `md5sum` and others. `md5sum` is faster than `sha256sum` but probability of collision (situation where two files have same checksum) is a bit higher (but still enough).

Content of the file:

```
b1a58ac886f70cb65cc124bcc8e12a52659fbf5ce841956953d70d29b74869d7  a/resize2fs
c0e532634d14783bbd2ec1a1ed9bfc0b64da4a1efea2e9936fb97c6777ac1e10  a/btrfs-image
d00cdf58189e2171e3cb6610e6290c70ba03ecc0dc46b0570595d9187d769d2e  a/btrfs
fadc2874feb053947ac1a4d8f14df58dabc093fa00b92f01125497ac9a171999  a/badblocks
424cf438ac1b6db45d1f25e237f28cc22bd7098a7fdf0f9c402744dc3f6ea6f2  a/agetty
424cf438ac1b6db45d1f25e237f28cc22bd7098a7fdf0f9c402744dc3f6ea6f2  a/agetty-2
424cf438ac1b6db45d1f25e237f28cc22bd7098a7fdf0f9c402744dc3f6ea6f2  b/agetty
424cf438ac1b6db45d1f25e237f28cc22bd7098a7fdf0f9c402744dc3f6ea6f2  b/agetty-2
424cf438ac1b6db45d1f25e237f28cc22bd7098a7fdf0f9c402744dc3f6ea6f2  b/bridge
7e177d31c45ab550b27ca743e4502cc4be519de4c75b2f479f427930bcb7c7bd  a/bridge
9954909c3436bef767729b8f6034e5f12ef300fad16dc0e540bfa3c89c38b9c6  a/lvreduce
9954909c3436bef767729b8f6034e5f12ef300fad16dc0e540bfa3c89c38b9c6  a/lvreduce-2
```

You can even visually compare the files. Files with same content have same checksum. Notice that the SHA256 checksum is 64 hex digits/chars long (32 bytes).

#### 2 Find repeated lines

```sh
cat cksums | uniq -Dw 64 | sed 's/^\S*\s*//'
```

Output:

```
a/agetty
a/agetty-2
b/agetty
b/agetty-2
b/bridge
a/lvreduce
a/lvreduce-2
```

You can also group files with same contents:

```sh
cat cksums | uniq --group -w 64 --group | sed 's/^\S*\s*//'
```

```
a/resize2fs

a/btrfs-image

a/btrfs

a/badblocks

a/agetty
a/agetty-2
b/agetty
b/agetty-2
b/bridge

a/bridge

a/lvreduce
a/lvreduce-2
```

#### 3 List files for deletion

```sh
count=0
cat cksums | uniq --group -w 64 --group | sed 's/^\S*\s*//' | while read filename
do
  if [[ -z "$filename" ]]
  then
    if [[ 1 -lt "$count" ]]
    then
      echo "$prev"
    fi

    count=0
  else
    prev="$filename"
    ((count++))
  fi
done
```

Delete them by appending `| xargs rm -v` to `done`.